# Get token from client object in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

i have simple code and running discord bots.

```
    for client in clients:
        @client.obj.event
        async def on_message(message):
            if message.author.bot: 
                return
            await message.channel.send(client.obj.application.id)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for clnt in clients:
        loop.create_task(clnt.obj.start(clnt.token))
    loop.run_forever()
```

i want to get application token from client.obj to identify from which application i got message. yes i can do it with application.id but is it possible to get token from client object?

Comment: It's not possible to retrieve the token from a `discord.py` Client or Bot. But it looks like whatever your `client` object is already has a `token` attribute. Why not use that rather than `client.obj`?

Comment: i have multiple bots. also @client.obj.application.id always returns first bot id but messages work for all bots.